# VPS Arsys arroja error 404 pero los archivos estan bien alojados

Tags: linux

Tengo un servidor VPS y hoy tras realizar una actualización de Plesk no se pueden visualizar sus archivos.

Si accedes por FTP se ven correctamente y al panel de administración también puedo acceder, pero cuando tratos de visualizarlos por el navegador (he probado con los tres), me arroja un error 404, lo raro es que los archivos están en el mismo sitio en el que funcionaban antes de la actualización.

Un saludo.

Comment: Verifica la configuración de tu sevidor http, que por lo general es Apache, hasta donde recuerdo. Consulta la documentación de Plesk para que veas cómo se configura el servicio en comento.

Comment: Nada, sigue sin funcionar. El error que arroja es este: Not Found

The requested URL /infophp.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at 82.223.114.64 Port 80 Pero es que el archivo si que está ahí alojado y ayer funcionaba correctamente.

Comment: Hay muchas variables. USas fcgi? mod_PHP? Has leido los logs de error de Plesk? Que version a que version has actualizado? Por otro lado creo que este es una pregunta especifica de un panel de control. Quizas no sea el sitio apropiado. MIra esto -> https://talk.plesk.com/threads/everything-is-404.338353/

Comment: ¿Dónde me recomendarías hacer la consulta? De la versión 9.2.3 a la 9.3.0. Me arroja este error en el log, pero no puedo ni restaurar ni hacer nada Operation with the Container "vrtl10771" is finished with errors: Can not update packages: ' vzpkg update -q -p 10771' exec failed - Error unpacking rpm package openssh-server-4.3p2-82.el5.x86_64 ['One or more rpm failed.'] Error: /usr/share/vzyum/bin/yum failed, exitcode=1 .